# WPF: DataTrigger not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

In a WPF Project I have some restyled `DataGridColumnHeaders` of a `DataGrid` which show a `ComboBox` for each `DataGridColumnHeader`. When the user selects from the `ComboBox`'s the `SelectionChanged` handler (in the code behind) updates an `Array` of `ColumnOptionViewModel` objects on the `MainWindowViewModel` with the newest selection.

At this point some code also works out if there are any duplicate selections in this array, and then sets an `IsDuplicate` Boolean property on the `ColumnOptionViewModel` that are duplicates. The idea is that a `DataTrigger` picks up the change in `IsDuplicate` and changes the `Background` of a `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemTemplate` for the duplicate `ComboBox`'s to `Red`.

However, this trigger is not firing. The `IsDuplicate` properties are being set ok, and everything else works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the XAML for the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDataGrid"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

 <Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Records}">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cbo"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.ColumnOptions}"
                                          SelectionChanged="cbo_SelectionChanged">

                                     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbo, Path=SelectedItem.IsDuplicate}">
                                                    <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>   
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>    
</Grid>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(RecordProvider.GetRecords());
    }

    private void cbo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (MainWindowViewModel)DataContext;

        var selectionChangedCombo = (ComboBox)e.Source;

        var dataGridColumnHeader = selectionChangedCombo.TemplatedParent as DataGridColumnHeader;

        vm.ColumnSelections[dataGridColumnHeader.DisplayIndex] = selectionChangedCombo.SelectedItem as ColumnOptionViewModel;

        CheckForDuplicates();

    }

    private void CheckForDuplicates()
    {
        var vm = (MainWindowViewModel)DataContext;

        var duplicates = vm.ColumnSelections.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any())
            .SelectMany(g => g);

        foreach (var option in duplicates)
        {
            option.IsDuplicate = true;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnOptionViewModel> _columnOptions = new ObservableCollection<ColumnOptionViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel> _records = new ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel>();

    ColumnOptionViewModel[] _columnSelections = new ColumnOptionViewModel[3];

    public MainWindowViewModel(IEnumerable<Record> records)
    {
        foreach (var rec in records)
        {
            Records.Add(new RecordViewModel(rec));
        }

        ColumnOptions.Add(new ColumnOptionViewModel(TestDataGrid.ColumnOptions.ColumnOption1));
        ColumnOptions.Add(new ColumnOptionViewModel(TestDataGrid.ColumnOptions.ColumnOption2));
        ColumnOptions.Add(new ColumnOptionViewModel(TestDataGrid.ColumnOptions.ColumnOption3));

        ColumnSelections[0] = ColumnOptions[0];
        ColumnSelections[1] = ColumnOptions[1];
        ColumnSelections[2] = ColumnOptions[2];

    }

    public ObservableCollection<ColumnOptionViewModel> ColumnOptions
    {
        get { return _columnOptions; }
        set { _columnOptions = value; }
    }

    public ColumnOptionViewModel[] ColumnSelections
    {
        get { return _columnSelections; }
        set { _columnSelections = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel> Records
    {
        get { return _records; }
        set { _records = value; }
    }
}
```

ColumnOptionViewModel :

```
public class ColumnOptionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ColumnOptions _colOption;

    public ColumnOptionViewModel(ColumnOptions colOption )
    {
        _colOption = colOption;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _colOption.ToString(); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    private bool _isDuplicate = false;
    public bool IsDuplicate
    {
        get { return _isDuplicate; }
        set
        { _isDuplicate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

ViewModelBase :

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check if changing any other property of textbox works in datatrigger (e.g. FontWeight to Bold)?

Comment: @Arie, tried changing FontWeight to Bold as suggested but still not firing.

Comment: How is your `OnPropertyChanged` method implemented? You are not passing name of property so it might be problem there (there are implementations without parameter, but just to be sure).

Comment: @Shadowed, please see edit above to see ViewModelBase implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to bind to the `IsDuplicate` property of the `SelectedItem` in the `ComboBox` you could use a `RelativeSource`.

You should also set the `Value` property of the `DataTrigger` to true/false depending on when you want the `Background` property of the `TextBlock` to be set to `Red`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.ColumnOptions}"
                  SelectionChanged="cbo_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.IsDuplicate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi @mm8, it was the missing `Value` property that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mm8, do you know why when I extend the `DataTemplate` by putting a `Border` around the `TextBlock` and Triggers section I get 3 build errors? One is 'The member 'Triggers' is not recognised or accessible'. The second is 'The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in the type `DataTemplate`. The third is 'The attached property 'DataTemplate.Triggers` is not defined on 'Border' or one of its base classes. I suspect err 3 is the most helpful, but I'm not sure what I need to do to the XAML to work around this? Could you help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I've since found that if I apply the `Trigger` directly on the `TextBlock` as @Arie suggested then everything works as expected, so I'm then able to have a `Border` in the `DataTemplate`. Still not sure what was going on though!

Answer (score 1):

As **@mm8** said, the `Value` is not chosen in your `DataTrigger`.

If that doesn't work, you can try using `Trigger` directly on `TextBlock` instead of `DataTemplate.Triggers`:

```
   <TextBlock>
       <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDuplicate}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
         </TextBlock.Style>
      </TextBlock>
```

Also, background and foreground values in controls that have selectable items can be tricky. For example, you may want to disable default selection colors (unfortunately then you will have to manage selected/focused background yourself):

```
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: Hi @Arie, thanks for your help. It was the missing `Value` property that was the problem.

Comment: Hi @Arie, thanks for your tip with applying the trigger directly on the `TextBlock`, as it helped me further with the next problem I encountered (see comments below in @mm8 answer). Thank you.